# Nestjs: import modules undefined, but methods and functions from modules can be imported

Tags: node.js, typescript, webstorm, nestjs, ts-node

I am using `Nestjs` with WebStorm & TS 4.2.3^latest.

The problem that I am facing is a bit strange. For example, some modules, like `axios` can be installed, imported, and used as usual. But some modules, *especially Nodejs Core, like `fs` or `path`*, can't be imported as modules. **BUT** their methods can be imported and used just fine!

```js
// ERROR: Module undefined on run:dev, but no error in IDE
import path from 'path';
import fs from 'fs';

// Working fine
import { join } from 'path';
import { readFileSync } from 'path';
```

I am sure, they have correct TS types, even installed manually. For example:

```
import axios from 'axios';
import path from 'path'; // path is undefined
import { join } from 'path';
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';

@Injectable()
export class AppService {
  async test(input: string): Promise<void> {
    // working fine
    await axios.get() 
    // Cannot read property 'join' of undefined
    await path.join() 

    // await join() Works fine!
  }
}
```

I have only one `tsconfig.json` which is generated by Nest Cli. I am starting my apps via `npm start:dev -name` and IDE doesn't show any errors in code until I run code.

[image: Example]

tsconfig.json module part, just to be sure: `"module": "commonjs"`, package.json doesn't have `module` part at all.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

IDE in this case, misdirect me a bit. Almost forgot, that I am dealing with TS now. Some modules seem to have no default exports, so:

- You should import as with them: `import * as fs from 'fs';`
- Or, another option is enabling: `"esModuleInterop": true,` in your `tsconfig.json`

Comment: Thanks. IDE was auto importing but import wasn't correct as you stated.

Comment: Just had this same issue, also with IntelliJ IDEs.

Comment: enabling: `"esModuleInterop": true`  in your `tsconfig.json` solved that for me