# How to solve the problem with nestjs and elasticsearch?

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch, nestjs

I have all the packages installed, but at startup, it gives me an error. Can someone help me, how should I solve this problem?

My package.json file:

[image]

`node_modules` elastic search module directory (ls):
[image]

Error:
[image]

Comment: I wasn't able to reproduce this. The types are loaded here. Looks like your `node_modules` is outdated or something like that.

Comment: @MicaelLevi I completely deleted the node_module folder and installed the most recent versions of the packages, but this did not solve the problem

Comment: take a screenshot of `ls -l node_modules/@nestjs/elasticsearch` and add it into your question please. Also, show us your tsconfig file

Comment: @MicaelLevi I have added a screenshot

Answer (score 0):

First of all, welcome to StackOverflow, please read the [guidelines before asking questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Using images, instead of `code` tags is a bad habit. That included formatting of the text, too.

The second thing is, as Micael mentioned, something is wrong with your project. Probably you don't install types for `@elasticsearch`. In some libs, they are not prebuilt, but installed separately from `@types`. Some libs don't have the necessary types at all.

*Deleting a `node_modules` folder and reinstalling the app, is the best option here.*

Otherwise, it could be bad project initialization. Try Nest CLI for sure. Or wrong `tsconfig.json` options.

Please check closely for the following values in your `tsconfig.json`:

```json
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
```

(*In case you have troubles with importing libs, instead of separate methods in NestJs, take a look [at my other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67032343/nestjs-import-modules-undefined-but-methods-and-functions-from-modules-can-be/67032443#67032443), it may help you*)

If I remember it correctly, the current `elasticsearch` lib in the middle of new types-support refactoring. So some of the types in the lib could be missing or imported badly.